# Add CheckBox To DataGridView Cell Programmatically

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I’m trying to add a CheckBox programmatically to a DataGridVew cell if the cell next to it has a value of “1”. I’m trying to do this as the rows are added

I’m hoping someone can help me out with the correct code here. I understand one of the lines of code is incorrect but I’ve put it in to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance.

```
    Private Sub Controls_DGV_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles Controls_DGV.RowsAdded

        If Controls_DGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = "1" Then
            Controls_DGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).AddCheckBox ' THIS LINE IS INCORRECT
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do. However, I hope you do realize that you can NOT “add” a check box cell to a single row in the grid. If you add a check box “column” then obviously this column will apply to ALL rows. Assuming you add a single check box column next to the cells that may contain 1… what do you want the check box cell to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same as @miguel except for the checking the value, in this case [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) is `On` as it should be.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub dataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) _
        Handles dataGridView1.RowsAdded

        If CStr(dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value) <> "1" Then
            dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = False
            dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0) = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
            dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = ""
            dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).ReadOnly = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddRowsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles AddRowsButton.Click

        For index As Integer = 0 To 5
            If CBool(index Mod 2) Then
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(False, "0")
            Else
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(False, "1")
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The column number 1 that you want to display a checkbox should already be of type DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn and then if the value is not "1" you can transform the type of the cell for a DataGridViewTextBoxCell, so there is no checkbox and you can even put there some text if you want. Because you're using 3 columns, i'll try to do the same.

In your Form1_Load() you should have something like this if you are adding columns programmatically:

```
    Dim ChkBox As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    Controls_DGV.Columns.Add("TextBox1", "TextBox1")
    Controls_DGV.Columns.Add(ChkBox)
    Controls_DGV.Columns.Add("TextBox2", "TextBox2")
```

Then using your code it should be like this:

```
    Private Sub Controls_DGV_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles Controls_DGV.RowsAdded

        If Controls_DGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value <> "1" Then
             ' replace the checkbox cell by textbox cell
             Controls_DGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1) = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
             Controls_DGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = "(empty or some text)"
        End If
    End Sub
```